# C# static constructor and GetVersion() any suggestions?

Tags: c#, static, constructor

C# static constructor and GetVersion() any suggestions?

Hi,
I have defined struct like this in separate file OSVERSIONINFO.cs like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct OSVERSIONINFO
{
    public static int SizeOf 
    {
        get 
        { 
            return Marshal.SizeOf (typeof(OSVERSIONINFO)); 
        }
    }

    public uint dwOSVersionInfoSize;
    public uint dwMajorVersion;
    public uint dwMinorVersion;
    public uint dwBuildNumber;
    public uint dwPlatformId;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string szCSDVersion;
}
```

Also I have this file OS.cs in which I have defined the following class:

```
public static class OS
{
    static OS ()
    {
        OSVERSIONINFO info = new OSVERSIONINFO();
        info.dwOSVersionInfoSize = (uint)OSVERSIONINFO.SizeOf;

        if (!OS.GetVersion(ref info)) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!!!");
        }

    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetVersion (ref OSVERSIONINFO lpVersionInfo);
}
```

Way in static constructor of OS class population of info (instance of OSVERSIONINFO struct) fails?
If I call OS.GetVersion in other palce (not OS class) every thing is OK?

Comment: You haven't shown the code for OS.GetVersion, and you haven't said in what way it fails.

Comment: Is GetVersion() declared static?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `Environment.OSVersion` to access the OS version information?

Comment: I am sorry I left off GetVersion() of OS class :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet -> Variable 'info' is not populated.

Comment: If the call fails, you should `throw new Win32Exception()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question, you need to call [`GetVersion`**`Ex`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: From MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724439%28VS.85%29.aspx) about GetVersion: This function has been superseded by GetVersionEx. New applications should use GetVersionEx or VerifyVersionInfo. Shame on me, I should read MSDN first. Thank you for your answer and time.

Answer (score 8):

You should use the [`Environment.OSVersion.Platform` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operatingsystem.platform.aspx) instead.